# Diagrammatic method to model software components, their interactions & I/O

Tags: uml, diagram

I'd like to model software components and their interaction between them, what information is passed, what processes take place in each component(not too detailed) and a clear specification of the input/output of the components.

What i've seen so far in UML is far too abstract and doesn't go into too much detail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about things you already know will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Someg guys Design programs on papers as diagrams,**

**Then  pass them to  software developer to Contruct.**

This appraoach is tried: "Clever guys" do modeling, and pass models to "ordinary" developers to do laborious task. **And this not worked.**

We like analogies. So many times we make analogy to construction industry where some guys do models-bluprints and other do building-contruction.And we first think that UML or other models diagrams are equivalent to construction industry models-blueprints. But it seems that we are wrong.

> To make an analogy with construction industry our blueprints are not
>   models-diagrams, our blueprints are actually the code we write.

**Detailed Paper Models like Cooking Receipes**

It is not realistic to design a software system entirely on a paper with detailed models upfront.Software development is iterative and incremental process.

Think of a map maker who make a paper map of city  as big as city, since the modeler include every details without any abstraction level.Will it be usefull?

**Is Modeling Useless ?**

Definitely not. But you should apply it to difficult part of your problem-solution space, not every trival part of them.

So instead of giving every details of system on paper to developers, explore difficult part of problem-solution space with developers face to face using visual diagrams.

> In software industry like it or hate it, Source Code is still the
>   King. And all models are liar until they are implemented and tested

Comment: seems legit as an answer! But what if i want to model those difficult parts in a BIT more detail than UML allows? Should i use a ''modified/more detailed'' component diagram? Any suggestions?  What you are saying is generally what i thought as well but some parts just beg me to model them to clear up any misunderstandings or ambiguities in maintainance or when i want to scale the web-app.

Comment: I do not know your context.But UML is not a good choice for a very detailed-precise specification. Maybe you can use Object Constraint Language to give more precise definitions to models. But if UML just  does not fit your work, just  do not use it...Think pragmatic and simple...Maybe to use simple tools such as a plain list of inputs-outputs,preconditions-postconditions ...

Comment: To get short info about other modeling methods used in software development just check the book "Modeling Software Behavior: A Craftsman's Approach" by Paul C. Jorgensen  http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781420080759